# Composer install says following errors in production environment

Tags: php, composer-php

When I try to install composer in prod,I got the following error while installing composer,can any one please suggest me help.Thanks.

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.5.0].
- doctrine/annotations v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
- Installation request for doctrine/cache v1.7.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.7.1].
- doctrine/cache v1.7.1 requires php ~7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
 Problem 3
- Installation request for doctrine/collections v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/collections[v1.5.0].
- doctrine/collections v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
 Problem 4
- Installation request for doctrine/common v2.8.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.8.1].
- doctrine/common v2.8.1 requires php ~7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
 Problem 5
- Installation request for doctrine/dbal v2.6.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[v2.6.2].
- doctrine/dbal v2.6.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 6
- Installation request for doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
- doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
 Problem 7
- doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
- phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.4 requires doctrine/instantiator ^1.0.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 3.4.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[3.4.4].
```

Comment: which part of `requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement` is unclear to you?

Comment: It requires php version 7.1 minimum

Answer (score 8):

it's more  simple  solution  than editing composer.json

use  switch  `--ignore-platform-reqs`  with composer command 
for example

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 2):

Either your composer.lock was made on a computer that runs PHP7.1, but your prod server is running 7.0.22, or your version constraints on (i guess) doctrine are too high.
To circumvent the first, add this to your composer.json:

`...
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0.22"
        }
    }
...`
, run `composer update` and check in the resulting composer.lock file. This way you force composer to choose packages for your production php version, which should be compatible to your dev version (7.1).

Comment: @Thomos,changed config in composer.json and uploaded in prod still same error remains.

Comment: could you pastebin your composer.json and composer.lock somewhere?